# How to display XML data in a web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding, web-applications

I am fetching data from a database. One of the fields contains the request data in XML format. Instead of showing it in the column, I have placed a button inside that cell and on click of that button, I want that XML data to load in a browser.
How to achieve that? 
I know how to load data in a browser from an XML file if it is placed locally but how to display it in a browser or in a **pop-up window** instead on button click if I am getting it as a result of the query?

[image: Current View]

Upon clicking View XML, it should display XML data in a web browser.

To display it from a file, I was using this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewXML" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" runat="server" 
                    Text="View XML" OnClick="ViewXML" />

protected void ViewXML(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/requestData.xml"));
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say `request data in XML format` you mean xml content from database field, or the current http request in xml?

I am assuming the first, that is it is a database field.

on the `view xml` button, pass in the row unique id then when post back fetch the xml from database then write it to response.

something like:

```
// pass in the row id in command argument

<asp:Button ID="btnViewXML" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" runat="server" 
                    Text="View XML"  CommandArgument='<%= row.Id %>' OnCommand="ViewXML" />


protected void ViewXML(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // id of row
    string id =e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    // fetch from db to get your xml content
    string xmlContent = ...;


    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
    Response.Write(xmlContent);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

if my assumption is wrong, then you will have to store your http request somewhere so when post back you can retrieve it. Either way, logic is pretty much the same, just where you getting the xml content is different.

---

### further explanation on using popup

there is a lot of different popup widget on web

I am using jquery ui as example, you can use other popup widget with roughly same logic

before writing the popup, one thing to consider is how you pass in the data (xml result in your case).

there is two way:

1. save your content some where on the page with first request
2. use ajax to load it only when button is click

I will use first way as example

on your page, create a div which will hold your popup content and init it with dialog without open, and also create a function for showing popup

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false        
    });
}

function showPopup(content){
    $('#dialog').text(content);
    $('#dialog').dialog("open");
}
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Xml Result">
</div>
```

then when you render your button, add a client button click to trigger the popup

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewXML" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" runat="server" 
                    Text="View XML"  onclientclick="showPopup('<%: row.XmlResult%>')"/>
```

depend size of your result data and the chance of user clicking the view xml result, using ajax may give better performance

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly fine. 
Can you guide me how to open it in a pop-up window on the same page? like a message box etc?

Comment: @Nizami I have modify the answer to include some example about using popup.  If you have more question on that topic, please open new question.  SO is more a QA site not like forum, so a question should focus on one thing only (hence what I did technically not a good practice in SO)